# is linking between requirement expressed by user and code using code comment a good idea?

Tags: java, specifications

I have a document where I specifiy user requirement using REQxxx as an ID for each requirement.
sometimes in the source code I conclude that a specific code block correspond to a specific requirement, so I write something like this

```
        // append TestStepResultEntity only for the Step Result View RQ001
        if( !(newEntity instanceof TestScenarioResultEntity && this.getUserObject() instanceof TestSuiteResultEntity))
            for (Object item : ((RootEntity<?, ?>) newEntity).getItems())
                newNode.NewItemAddedToEntityEventHappened(item);
```

is this a code idea ? are there any best practices regarding these things ??

Comment: I think the fundamental question is - who is going to use this linkage information, and for what purpose?

Comment: it will be used for maintenance or evolution purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If/when requirements change, these type of comments are rarely updated - meaning I have no idea whether the comment is still valid or is now obsolete or perhaps even wrong and misleading.

I could perhaps do a text search for REQ123 when requirements change and update accordingly, but this seems like bureaucratic overhead and would probably degrade quite rapidly. Especially in large teams.

Compare this with a comment that explains what the code-block actually does: I can often - and without consulting other systems - quite quickly see whether the comment is still valid. In such a situation, it is more likely that I would edit the comment, thus improving code quality.

Having said that, these comments might (as previously mentioned) be meaningful in acceptance tests.

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally stick this sort of information in a unit or acceptance test, for example have a test called

```
@Test
public void shouldAppendTestStepResultEntityOnlyForTheStepResultView_RQ001() {
    ...
}
```

The test should prove the requirement is implemented and will document your code in a useful way for future developers (*sort of*).

Comment: I also agree with @DNA though, you probably don't really ever need to mention RQ001 if no one will ever use it!!

Comment: it will be used for maintenance or evolution purpose.

if another developer wants to work with my code and he notice that a block of code correspond to a specific requirement, he will know that if user want to change this requirement, he will modify this code block !!!!

Comment: @AnouarBAKRI I should say the reason is the opposite... if you (or another developer) stumble with a code that does X, that information will tell the developer if X is required by the system or he may change it by X' without breaking the user requirements. It will rare that a new user requirement means that you only need to modify the code marked as X (unless it is very minor).

Comment: @SJuan76 sorry I don't understand what you are triyng to say

Comment: @SJuan76 basically, if you write tests that verify your requirements, the code has sort of documented itself. If any developer changes anything in the future, they can run all the tests and if they all pass then they can have confidence that REQ001 still works (I might have mistook your comment as a reply to me there...)